# Standard tables for series values

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request

What are standard books where one can lookup values of functions that cannot be calculated analytically?

For example, I want to know the value of
$$S(\alpha)=\sum_{x=1}^\infty\sum_{y=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}^{~\alpha}}~,$$

but I don't know of an analytical solution. I can calculate the sums brute-force for any given value of $\alpha$, but to me it looks like something that many people may have calculated before.

Where would one look to find such values?

Answer (score 0):

A standard reference work for tables of mathematcal function values is [Abramowitz and Stegun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abramowitz_and_Stegun).